# selenium exceptionin java (org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know there are number of threads running but none of them has a solution of this problem. I am trying to get a aspx page using selenum. But it throws UnreachableBrowserException at this line of code `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`. An instance of chrome is opening but then later on after few seconds it throws the exception I have mentioned above.

Here is my sample code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
           "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://some aspx page with form");
            System.out.println("!!!!! Got the page !!!!!");
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
```

Following is the stacktrace.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: 'fbe29a9', time: '2014-02-19 20:54:28'
System info: host: 'E7D4C9EFE70614', ip: '192.168.1.12', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:567)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startSession(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:149)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
    at HtmlParser.main(HtmlParser.java:31)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: 'fbe29a9', time: '2014-02-19 20:54:28'
System info: host: 'E7D4C9EFE70614', ip: '192.168.1.12', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:546)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:12233/status] to be available after 20008 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
    ... 12 more
```

I have red number of articles but couldnot find any solution. My chrome version is 33.0.1750.154 m.

Comment: What is your chrome browser version? Can you just check that and mention here?

Comment: its showing Version 33.0.1750.146 m

Comment: I have updated it and now the version is 33.0.1750.154 m

Comment: Problem Solved :). I have downloaded chromedriver and instead of setting path to chrome.exe i set the path to the chromedriver.exe and it worked. C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have downloaded `chromedriver` and instead of setting path to `chrome.exe` I set the path to `chromedriver.exe` and it worked. 
**C:\Program Files(x86)\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe**