# WebDriver exception after SoapUI project execution

Tags: java, selenium, soap, soapui

Please help to resolve the below issue.

I am using the Eclipse.My main class call the 2 below class/java file.

1) `Invoke_SoapUI_Project.java`  ( this executes the SOAP UI project )
2) `Run_Selenium_Script.java`   ( This opens one of the URL from Firefox ).

My main function call the above `Invoke_SoapUI_Project.java` and triggers the execution of "SOAP UI XML Project" and it runs well.

Then my second function "`Run_Selenium_Script.java`" calls and it tries to open the one of Webpage. but getting the below error at the line where i am defining `webdriver` object. i.e `driver= new firefoxDriver();`

But if i comment the  `Invoke_SoapUI_Project.java`, then i won't get below exceptions, the firefox object creates properly and it opens the my URL.

The below exception i am getting:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
System info: host: 'BDC8-L-HP26ZR1', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at Services.CommonFunctions.setUp(CommonFunctions.java:1481)
    at Services.CommonFunctions.obj_run(CommonFunctions.java:1631)
    at Services.CSS_Validation_a.print(CSS_Validation_a.java:283)
    at Services.CSS_main.main(CSS_main.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.determineProxy(SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.java:79)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultRoutePlanner.java:76)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.determineRoute(InternalHttpClient.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:362)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2):

We stumbled across what appears to be the same problem here (took us quite some time) but we managed to work around it:

The Problem seems to be that SoapUI sets the default proxyselector to null and Apache httpclient is not expecting this.

Reproducing the Problem:

```
WsdlProject wsdlProject = new WsdlProject("");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Workaround:

```
ProxySelector proxy = ProxySelector.getDefault();
WsdlProject wsdlProject = new WsdlProject("");
ProxySelector.setDefault(proxy);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

peidong-hu sent a patch for standalone two days ago (took the solution from there):
https://github.com/Ardesco/selenium-standalone-server-plugin/issues/23

I already filed an error report for selenium, will update it with this details: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/388

I'm also going to file a report for SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425565/selenium-exceptionin-java-org-openqa-selenium-remote-unreachablebrowserexceptio)

You need to set the firefox driver and provide it as system property.
For eg:
`System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "c:/webdriver/firefoxdriverpath");`

Comment: Hi, still i am facing problem, i am completely blocked here. please help me.  Browser exception occurs every time after execution of SOAP UI Code. Browser exception occurs when i am trying to create driver object like :   driver = new firefoxdriver();

Comment: Did you follow the link mentioned? Can post the code?

Answer (score 0):

I also found this issue when using SoapUI 5. I checked the source code.
In the class `ProxyUtils`, the method `setGlobalProxy()` will set the `proxySelector` to null if you don't set the proxy or set the proxy to Automatic.

```
 public static void setGlobalProxy( Settings settings )
    {
    ProxySelector proxySelector = null;
    ProxySettingsAuthenticator authenticator = null;
    if( proxyEnabled )
    {
        if( autoProxy )
        {
        proxySelector = new ProxyVoleUtil().createAutoProxySearch().getProxySelector();
        }
        else
        {
            proxySelector = getManualProxySelector( settings );
        }
        if( proxySelector != null )
        {
            // Don't register any proxies for other schemes
            proxySelector = filterHttpHttpsProxy( proxySelector );
        }
        authenticator = new ProxySettingsAuthenticator();
    }
    *ProxySelector.setDefault( proxySelector );*
    Authenticator.setDefault( authenticator );
    HttpClientSupport.setProxySelector( proxySelector );
    HttpClientSupport.getHttpClient().setCredentialsProvider( getProxyCredentials( settings ) );
    }
```

In Windows OS, `proxySelector = new ProxyVoleUtil().createAutoProxySearch().getProxySelector();` also will be null.

```
 if (PlatformUtil.getCurrentPlattform() != PlatformUtil.Platform.WIN) {
            proxySearch.addStrategy(ProxySearch.Strategy.BROWSER);
            // For Windows both BROWSER and OS_DEFAULT will end up with an IEProxySearchStrategy.
            // The call in createPacSelector to winHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl is quite slow and we don't want to do it twice.
        }
```

My solution is modify the `ProxyUtils` class. Change `ProxySelector.setDefault( proxySelector );` to

```
    if(proxySelector != null){
        ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector);
    }
    else{
        proxySelector = ProxySelector.getDefault();
    }
```

Then I use my own `ProxyUtils.class`, update the `ProxyUtils.class` in `soapui-xxx.jar` (in `SOAPUI_HOME\bin\`) through WinRAR or 7Z. Now my SoapUI works very well.